# How to determine color palettes visible for the colorblind?

Tags: accessibility, color, color-blindness

How can I create a color palette that can still be visible by those who are colorblind? Is there a resource that can help determine if color palettes meet WCAG standards?

If not, could someone explain their process for ensuring maximum accessibility when choosing color palettes?

Comment: I've tested [material design color palettes](https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html) and they are designed with that in mind. You can try the [NoCoffee](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/NoCoffee%20Vision%20Simulator?hl=en&gl=US) chrome extension to simulate a lot of visual impairments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Smashing Magazine did a huge [article in October 2014 on best practices in color accessibility design](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/10/22/color-contrast-tips-and-tools-for-accessibility/). It covers the forms of color blindness and a number of tools to validate your designs. Here's a copy of the best practices outlined there:

> Test for color-contrast ratio, and document the styles and color codes used for all design elements. Create a visual design specification that includes the following:
>
> - typography for all textual elements, including headings, text links, body text and formatted text;
> - icons and glyphs and text equivalents;
> - form elements, buttons, validation and system error messaging;
> - background color and container styles (making sure text on these backgrounds all pass);
> - the visual treatments for disabled links, form elements and buttons (which do not need to pass a minimum color-contrast ratio).

And here're a couple of tools for testing contrast I have found that aren't mentioned in the article:

- [WCAG Contrast checker for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/wcag-contrast-checker/)
- [Colour Contrast Analyser for Mac & Windows](http://www.paciellogroup.com/resources/contrastanalyser/) (free app that compares contrast of colors and simulates color blindness for a portion of the screen)
- [Color blindness simulator for Mac only](https://michelf.ca/projects/sim-daltonism/)

Answer (score 1):

I've found that it's pretty hard to find concrete examples or How-To's.

Adobe products like Illustrator have very helpful simulators (open a new Window and choose View > Proof Setup > Color Blindness...) that can instantly show you a live side-by-side rendition as you tweak your colors. And there are free standalone tools as well, like Colour Contrast Analyzer.

I've posted an example at [graphicdesign.stackexchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/926/good-color-palette-usable-for-the-color-blind/67161#67161)